# how to create Global variable and how to set data set value into Global Variable

Tags: birt

1. i created a Rreport varialble
   [image]

2. i have a dataset value "dyna". i write the script "reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("dynamic", this.getRowData().getColumnValue("dyna"));" in onCreate Method of "dyna" Field.
   [image]

3.I draged and droped variable in my report to see both result ame or not. when i run this report Both are giving different Results.
[image]

Please Help in , how to set the global variable
Thanks